# Installing APC. Use pecl or apt-get?

Tags: 12.04, server, php

I have seen guides that use `apt-get install php-apc` and guides that use `pecl install apc`.

Is one method better then the other? Or is just two different methods of installing the same thing? What is the difference?

From what I read it seems that using `pecl install` will get a later version, is that right?

Using Ubuntu 12.04-64bit if it matters. Thanks.

Comment: I think php-apc is broken in Ubuntu, last I checked it was at least.

Comment: Both methods of installing APC worked for me. Using pecl, I had to install a additional package or two or else it would get a error and abort installation. I was just wondering if one method does something addtional...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on if you want to manage upgrades with `apt-get` or `pecl`. Either way there's no real benefit to one vs the other.

Answer (score 6):

The difference is that PECL will provide you with a newer version of APC.

- PECL will install the latest released version, 3.1.13 at the time of this writing
- APT will install 3.1.7 on 12.04 LTS

See the differences on the changelog: http://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=APC&release=3.1.7

All in all:

- **If you don't care too much about the version, use APT since it's easier to maintain**
- **If you need some of the most recent features or fix, use PECL**

Answer (score 5):

"PECL is a repository for PHP Extensions, providing a directory of all known extensions and hosting facilities for downloading and development of PHP extensions."<sup>**1**</sup> PECL comes with the php-pear package.

To install the APC,

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install php-apc
```

***Note: On newer releases of Ubuntu, APC is available from the package manager; however if using older Ubuntu release and you can't find an apc-php package. You can the install via PECL, but some dependencies need to be installed, then PECL can be used to install APC.***

<sup>**1**</sup> ["What is PECL?"](http://pecl.php.net/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand what PECL is and how to install APC using apt-get. I was curious what the differences were between the two methods? Is one method better then the other?

Comment: Thanks worked for me _sudo apt-get install php-apc_ with PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17 ;-)